# paypal in-context checkout reverts back to classic express checkout

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I've been trying to switch over our classic express checkout to in-context express checkout.

As instructed, I've switched the URL to https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/

This is the HTML snippet in the cart:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
 <a id="paypalcheckout" href="paypal_checkout/PostToPaypal.cfm?orderidentifier=XXXX">
    <img class="paypal-button-hidden" src="/img/paypal.png" alt="" class="img-responsive center-block"/>
 </a>
</div>

<script> 
  window.paypalCheckoutReady = function() {
     paypal.checkout.setup("ZZZZ", {locale: 'en_US', environment: 'sandbox', button: ['paypalcheckout']}); 
 } 
</script>
<script async src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
```

PostToPaypal.cfm makes the necessary api requests and gets back the EC-code and then redirects to this link:

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow/2?incontext=1&token=EC-YYYY

The click results in a pop up window with the main window going dark.  But after a few seconds,  the pop up window makes the main page go to classic checkout and closes.  It's letting me continue and checkout successfully with the old method.  So I know the EC number is correct. Can anyone help me understand what I need to do to make in-context checkout work?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm doing this too, where did you have switched the URL to https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow/  ? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the issue was the `CALLBACK` param when getting transaction id. When I removed it, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem.

The solution turned out to be in the server-side settings.
In the paypalfunctions.php file (which PayPal itself generated for me), there are a couple of lines that you need to remove, ones pertaining to it being a **digital** item.
Look for a similar line:

```
$nvpstr .= "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY" . $index . "=Digital";
```

It might be repeated several times.
Basically, the Digital Goods are not allowed through the in-context checkout, which is why I was getting the redirect issue.

Comment: this was the answer for me. PayPal documentation is a mess!

Comment: @brainondev I went to upvote you but it turns out your existing upvote was already me. The documentation is awful. They don't actually explain WHY they are doing certain things which is the biggest issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with LANDINGPAGE set to Billing.

In that particular case sandbox reverts to classic express checkout version.
In production both Billing and Login values for LANDINGPAGE  parameter result in a correct popup window.

Comment: Did you ever find out how to fix this in sandbox mode ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove these parameters to get it to work

```
FlatRateShippingOptions 
cppHeaderImage
CallbackURL
CallbackTimeout
```