# paypal in-context checkout loading in lightbox and after few seconds revert to classic express check out

Tags: javascript, php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

paypal in-context checkout loading in lightbox  and after few seconds revert to classic express check out.
i read this post [paypal in-context checkout reverts back to classic express checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898739/paypal-in-context-checkout-reverts-back-to-classic-express-checkout)
but it didnt help

```
<form class="ajaxasync">
<button id="t2" type="submit" class="checkout" class="paypal-button-hidden">
    <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
</button>
```

```
$scope.paypalArray['method'] ="SetExpressCheckout";
$scope.paypalArray['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT']= "1.00";
$scope.paypalArray['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE'] = "USD";
$scope.paypalArray['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION'] = "Sale";
$scope.paypalArray['returnUrl']= "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/curl?success=true";
$scope.paypalArray['cancelUrl'] = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/expresscheckout/curl?cancel=true";
$scope.paypalArray['version'] = "124.0";
$scope.paypalArray['USER'] = "myuserid@gmail.com";
$scope.paypalArray['PWD']= "9MKJCKB9JLSDEHD";
$scope.paypalArray['signature'] = "ABObRIVX-x21JGHTHGJJKLyToPvwtHhA90pM0a-gaGJs54hytrf2OzBfd";
$scope.paypalArray['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0'] = "item";
$scope.paypalArray['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0'] = "1.00";
$scope.paypalArray['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0'] = "1";


window.paypalCheckoutReady = function() {
        paypal.checkout.setup("56EJUS986TVWQ", {
            environment: 'sandbox',
            click: function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var url = paypal.checkout.urlPrefix + "EC%2d54U76817C6392042J";
                paypal.checkout.startFlow(url);
            },
            button: ['t2']
        });
    };
```

the first api call i am doing to get token return with success. after i put the token to open the paypal lightbox window. the light box open for a few seconds with blank page and then redirect to classic display express checkout. I couldent find any solution for that. 
The wired part is that if i copy paste the example form paypal its works well : http://plnkr.co/edit/RifUli3hDIq6kQJI0Ujc?p=preview

thanks in advance.

**ANSWER:**
my problem caused because i set to my test business  account region israel.

**supported countries:** 
In-Context checkout is only available for Merchant Accounts in: Australia, Austria, Belgium, Brazil (paymentaction=sale only), Canada, China, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Hong Kong, Ireland, Italy, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Turkey, the United Kingdom or the United States

Comment: I just want to say that I'm having the same problem. Things were working correctly for weeks, but the issue began late last night with no changes on my end.

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing an AJAX asynchronous checkout, you need to add the following line to the beginning of your click: function(event) function:

```
paypal.checkout.initXO();
```

**EDIT**: Actual issue ended up being your account is based in Israel. In-Context checkout is currently not available for merchant accounts in Israel.

Comment: Thanks for the comment . but its don't solve the issue. just for the test i add the token manually as you can see in the code.If there is error the popup window dont close or redirect to regular page. its only happen when the token is valid.

Comment: Do you have <script src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script> after your window.paypalCheckoutReady function?

Comment: yes.






 <form>
    <button id="t2"  class="" class="">
        <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif">
    </button>
</form>

<script async src="//www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

Comment: Okay, just confirming that the checkout.js is being run AFTER the window.paypalCheckoutReady. Checkout.js calls that function, so if the function isn't in the code already, it will not work as intended.

Comment: i think its connect to the values i passed. because i add my token and merchant id to this link  http://plnkr.co/edit/RifUli3hDIq6kQJI0Ujc?p=preview and the same bug happen again.

Comment: Are there any other variables you are passing over besides the ones listed in your code sample?

Comment: No.I only send the values in the code sample. What can be the cause to that?
   Or is there other method to try make it work?

Comment: So, on that plinker, you replace 'url' on line 36 with your EC Token, and your merchant ID on line 22 and it does the same thing? Can you please post one of your EC Token IDs so I can take a look at it?

Comment: TOKEN=EC%2d7KR34258EW797342M&TIMESTAMP=2015%2d10%2d13T21%3a02%3a58Z&CORRELATIONID=966704d3d2cb5&ACK=Success&VERSION=65%2e1&BUILD=18308778
IS there option to talk with you on skype?

Comment: TOKEN=EC%2d9XA24770BN163614V&TIMESTAMP=2015%2d10%2d13T21%3a06%3a51Z&CORRELATIONID=c90b5c5d488fc&ACK=Success&VERSION=124%2e0&BUILD=18308778              this is token with the values in the question.

Comment: I tried also this code http://www.techycommerce.com/uncategorized/express-checkout-in-context-integration-in-php/    the demo has bug because after login its redirect to classic checkout. and when i try this code on local env i get the same problem i had. i tried with two different  test business users.

Comment: I tried that demo and it worked as expected. I tried a couple other sandbox accounts I have and they're still working. It must be something with the sandbox accounts you are using. Which country is the test account you are using based out of? Unfortunately, right now we are experiencing issues with our sandbox where I cannot lookup the info on the EC tokens. I will try again tomorrow.

Comment: I am trying from israel.

Comment: I create test business user from US and its work. Is there a problem with users from ISRAEL?

Comment: In-Context checkout is only available for Merchant Accounts in: Australia, Austria, Belgium, Brazil (paymentaction=sale only), Canada, China, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Hong Kong, Ireland, Italy, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Turkey, the United Kingdom or the United States

Comment: This problem happen again . but now its happen after i login in the paypal popup window.  the window close and redirect to classic view to confirm the payment. 
token id = EC-18X231182W9051734

Comment: Only supports Buyer Accounts in: Australia, Austria, Belgium, Brazil, Canada, Denmark, France, Germany, Italy, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Turkey, the United Kingdom or the United States

Comment: See the full details at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/in-context/

Comment: token = EC-7CX45613YM9544252